# How to modify an array of objects if two following objects have different value?

Tags: javascript, foreach, comparison

Consider this `array`:

```
const arr = [
  {order: 1, mess:"test1"},
  {order: 2, mess:"test2"},
  {order: 2, mess:"test2"},
  {order: 2, mess:"test2"},
  {order: 3, mess:"test3"},
  {order: 4, mess:"test4"},
]
```

`arr` is always sorted by `order`.

I want to modify it to get:

```
const arr = [
  {order: 1, mess:"test1"},

  {order: 2, mess:"test2", sep:true},
  {order: 2, mess:"test2"},
  {order: 2, mess:"test2"},

  {order: 3, mess:"test3", sep:true},

  {order: 4, mess:"test4", sep:true},
]
```

`sep` must be inserted into an object if it has an `order` different from the preceding object.

I'm unable to write this function, even if it might be quite simple (I guess!).
At this time, I have this, but it doesn't work at all and I don't understand its behavior.

```js
const arr = [
  {order: 1, mess: "test1"},
  {order: 2, mess: "test2"},
  {order: 2, mess: "test2"},
  {order: 2, mess: "test2"},
  {order: 3, mess: "test3"},
  {order: 4, mess: "test4"},
  ]


arr.forEach(function(value, i) {
  i = Number(i)
  const y = i + 1
  if (arr[i] !== undefined && arr[y] !== undefined) {
    if (arr[i].order === arr[y].order) arr[y].sep = true;
  }
});

console.log(arr)
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: `i = Number(i)` is not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest change of existing array

```js
const arr = [{ order: 1, mess: "test1" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 3, mess: "test3" }, { order: 4, mess: "test4" }];

arr.forEach((value, i) => {
  if (i && arr[i-1].order !== arr[i].order) arr[i].sep = true;
});
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Works like a charme and change the current array! Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You could map a new array and check the item and the predecessor.

```js
const
    data = [{ order: 1, mess: "test1" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 3, mess: "test3" }, { order: 4, mess: "test4" }],
    result = data.map((o, i, a) => i && a[i - 1].order !== o.order
        ? { ...o, sep: true }
        : o
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
const arr = [
  {order: 1, mess: "test1"},
  {order: 2, mess: "test2"},
  {order: 2, mess: "test2"},
  {order: 2, mess: "test2"},
  {order: 3, mess: "test3"},
  {order: 4, mess: "test4"},
  ]

arr.forEach((obj,index)=>{
  if(index>0 && obj.order != arr[index-1]['order']){
    arr[index]['sep']=true
  }
});
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: why not `arr[index-1].order` no need for the bracket notation

Comment: yes, simple dot notation will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Changes original array:

```
arr.forEach((el, idx) => {
  if (idx === 0) {
    el.sep = true;
  } else {
    if (el.order !== arr[idx-1].order) {
      el.sep = true;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is another way to achieve the same result as you want.

I believe a more generalized way.

```
arr.forEach((obj, index) => {
  
  if(JSON.stringify(obj[index+1]) === JSON.stringify(obj[index+2])) {
    obj[index].sep = true;
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the array:

```
let arr2 = [...arr];
```

Shift it (so the first item is the second one!)

```
arr2.shift()
```

Loop over both

```js
const arr = [{ order: 1, mess: "test1" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 2, mess: "test2" }, { order: 3, mess: "test3" }, { order: 4, mess: "test4" }];
let arr2 = [...arr];
arr2.shift();
const result = [arr[0]];
let sep = true;
for (const [v1, v2] of [arr, arr2]) if (v1.order===v2.order) result.push(v2); else result.push({...v2, sep})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: That does not seem to work all the way